# A question in Lesson 4 of Hoffman Kunze Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

While self studying Linear Algebra from Hoffman Kunze I am unable to think the reasoning behind an argument in Lesson -4 of the book.

It's image :[image]

I think there is a typo in last 3rd line: There should be $f_j$ instead of $f_{i} $ .

Now,Question : How author changed the indexes to $g_{i} $ and $h_{n-i-j} $ is unclear to me while there is no problem with changing of index of both summations.

I would be really thankful if someone can explain it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The transition in question is
$$
\sum_{i=0}^n \sum_{j=0}^i f_jg_{i-j}h_{n-i} = \sum_{j=0}^n \sum_{i=0}^{n-j} f_jg_i h_{n-i-j}.
$$
They present the second sum with the $f_j$ factored out of the innermost summation, but otherwise it's the same.

There are two changes that simultaneously occur in this transition. First, we change the order of summation so that summation over $j$ moves to the outside. Second, we redefined what the index $i$ represents. We can apply these changes separately as follows.

For the change in order, note that the summation can be interpreted as $\sum_{(i,j) \in S} f_j g_{i-j}h_{n-i}$, where $S = \{0 \leq i \leq n \text{ and } 0 \leq i \leq j\}$.  We want to express $S$ in such a way that the inequality describing $j$ comes first. We have
$$
S = \{0 \leq i \leq n \text{ and } 0 \leq j \leq i\} = \{0 \leq j \leq n \text{ and } j \leq i \leq n\}.
$$
Accordingly, the sum can be expressed as
$$
\sum_{i=0}^n \sum_{j=0}^i f_jg_{i-j}h_{n-i} = \sum_{j=0}^n \sum_{i=j}^n f_j g_{i-j} h_{n-i}.
$$
This transition is analogous to a "change of order of integration" in multivariate calculus.

Now, we reindex the innermost sum by taking $k = i-j$. Note that $j \leq i \leq n \implies 0 \leq k \leq n-j$, which means that the above sum becomes
$$
\sum_{j=0}^n \sum_{i=j}^n f_j g_{i-j} h_{n-i} = 
\sum_{j=0}^n \sum_{k=0}^{n-j} f_j g_k h_{n - (k+j)} = 
\sum_{j=0}^n \sum_{k=0}^{n-j} f_j g_k h_{n -k - j}.
$$
Now, replacing the index $k$ with $i$ (which I think makes things more confusing) leads to
$$
\sum_{j=0}^n \sum_{k=0}^{n-j} f_j g_k h_{n -k - j} = 
\sum_{j=0}^n \sum_{i=0}^{n-j} f_j g_i h_{n -i - j},
$$
which was what we wanted.

Comment: I'm don't see the error that you're referring to

Comment: it's fine. I was confused. I am deleting my comment. Sorry!!